# Popular List c#

Tags: c#, lista

Estou tentando retornar dados de um list em um foreach. No primeiro foreach, ele está retornando os dados corretos, mas não está gravando na variavel nflist do primeiro foreach, então, assim que passa por ele novamente, perde os dados anteriores e substitui pelos dados atuais.

```
    public void UpdateNFE()
    {
        List<NFE> nfeList = new List<NFE>();
        NFEDB nfeData = new NFEDB();
        SAPBAPI sapBAPI = new SAPBAPI();
        NFE nfeTeste = new NFE();

        DataTable NFSap =  sapBAPI.SearchNFbyDate();

        foreach (DataRow item in NFSap.Rows)
        {
            int index = NFSap.Rows.IndexOf(item);

            nfeList = nfeData.ListNFEForUpdate(NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-NFENUM"].ToString(), NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-CREDAT"].ToString());

    //está retornando todos os dados corretamente, mas é necessário "gravar" 
    //os dados retornados

        }

        foreach (NFE nfe in nfeList)
        {
            StructureNFEAccessKey nfeAccessKey = new StructureNFEAccessKey();

            nfeAccessKey.REGIO = nfe.Region;
    }
```

Comment: Se você faz `nfeList = ...` dentro do `foreach` naturalmente que perde os valores anteriores. Se a ideia é ir adicionando coisas à lista terá que utilizar o método `Add` da lista para isso

Comment: Obrigada! Deu certo com nfeList.AddRange..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar o método nfeList.Add(item) ou nfeList.AddRange(items) para adicionar itens na sua lista, senão os valores antigos serão perdidos mesmo.

substitua:

```
  nfeList = nfeData.ListNFEForUpdate(NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-NFENUM"].ToString(), NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-CREDAT"].ToString());
```

Se o nfeData.ListNFEForUpdate for uma lista, insira isso:

```
nfeList.AddRange(nfeData.ListNFEForUpdate(NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-NFENUM"].ToString(), NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-CREDAT"].ToString()));
```

Se o nfeData.ListNFEForUpdate for um objeto unico do tipo NFE, insira isso:

```
nfeList.Add(nfeData.ListNFEForUpdate(NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-NFENUM"].ToString(), NFSap.Rows[index]["J_1BNFDOC-CREDAT"].ToString()));
```